# Split XML in Multiple XML files with the help of IBM Feature Packs?

Tags: java, xml

Is it possible to SPLIT the XML based on person tag element with the help of IBM Feature Packs?

```
<person>
    <name>a</name>
    <age>1</age>
</person>
<person>
    <name>b</name>
    <age>2</age>
</person>
<person>
    <name>c</name>
    <age>3</age>
</person>
```

Comment: Do you mean IBM® WebSphere® Application Server Feature Pack for XML? I guess so, but you can perform this basic task with the core Java runtime.

Comment: My requirement to use IBM® WebSphere® Application Server Feature Pack for XML. The input file will be a Source. I need to brake the Source in to multiple file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The Feature Pack for XML provides languages XPath 2.0, XSLT 2.0, and XQuery 1.0 to parse xml. Without the Feature Pack for XML, apparently you only have access to the 1.0 spec levels for each. But that may be enough for others. (I presume that's why you need this pack?)

> Without the feature pack, WebSphere Application Server version 7.0 contains support for
>   JAXP, implemented by the open source software library Xalan from the Apache Software
>   Foundation. This technology implements the XPATH and XSLT languages for processing XML
>   at the version 1.0 specification levels. The Feature Pack for XML delivers support for the
>   following versions of the XML processing languages:
>
> - XPath 2.0
> - XSLT 2.0
> - XQuery 1.0

So, for a simple XPath example, an xpath of `/person/*` *ought* to return:

```
<name>a</name>
<age>1</age>
<name>b</name>
<age>2</age>
<name>c</name>
<age>3</age>
```

Source: IBM Redbook, ["Getting Started with the WebSphere Application Server Feature Pack for XML"](https://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/iwm/web/signup.do?source=sw-app&S_PKG=ov1041&S_TACT=109KA6IW&S_CMP=web_opp_ibm_ws_appinfra_%20xmlfp)